# Insertion of data in two different tables using Entity Framework within single Button click in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

In my database I've 2 tables Employee and Address. In forms a single tab represents the fields of both tables. Under the click event of OK button i tried to insert the data but Exception occurred. I'am able to insert the data one table at a time but not both.

I'm having exception:

"an object with the same key already exists in ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in Modified state.
 An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager if it is in the Added State."

My code is:

```
        try
        {

            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
            {
                db.Connection.Open();

                string empid = txtEmpId.Text.ToString();

                Employee emp = db.Employees.Single(a => a.Emp_ID == empid);

                emp.Full_Name = txtFullName.Text;

                db.AddToEmployees(emp);

                db.SaveChanges();

                Address address = db.Addresses.Single(b => b.Emp_Id == empid);

                address.House_No = txtHouseNo.Text.ToString();

                db.AddToAddresses(address);

                db.SaveChanges();


                ts.Complete();

                MessageBox.Show("completed successfully");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (db.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                db.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Pl z help me out!

Comment: You should post some code that is relevant to what you are trying to do

Comment: As now i add the code so I'm looking forward for you reply

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of your posted code, you retrieve an address from the database, update it, but then try to add it back into the database?

This causes a primary key conflict since the record cannot be inserted twice.

Remove the line which adds the address to the database, since it is already in there.

Comment: These tables have primary/foreign key relationship.

Comment: I'm having the exception:

"an object with the same key already exists in ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in Modified state.
 An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager if it is in the Added State."

now i paste my code so help me with this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Transactions for inserting into the two tables as one SQL statement

[Transaction Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx)

Comment: I'm using the transaction in above way. Can u tell me which mistake I'm making?